# MouseHover Event : How can I find out the cordinates of the datagridview with mouseHover event

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find out the coordinates of datagridview cell by firing mousehover event to display tooltip. I'm using this coordinate to find data in the list which depends upon the coordinates of datagridview cell.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for col and row indices when mouse hovers over the datagridview cell.

Comment: Must you use the `MouseHover` event?  Why not use the `CellMouseMove` event instead and then access the `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` properties of the event args instance?

Comment: I tried CellMouseMove event but it doesn't respond immediately when I change the move in or out of the cell. At some point I have to click to display tooltip which shows information related to that particular cell.